# Get general taxonomy name for a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'd like to get the taxonomy name for a specific Custom Post Type.

For example:

I created a Custom Post Type `Portfolio` with a Taxonomy called `Skills`, I'd like to retrieve the `Skills`, which is the general name used for the taxonomies related with the `Portfolio` Custom post Type.

Any idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `wp_get_object_terms()` is what you are looking for. Take a look into this:

`$data = wp_get_object_terms( $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args );`

This will retrieve the associated terms with an object. For further reading, check this page from [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms).

**PS:** For a detailed answer, please share your code and research with us.